# Can I use 48 V, 20 Ah with a bike which came with 48 V, 13 Ah?

Tags: voltage, batteries, amperage, install

My eBike came with 48 V, 13 Ah battery. I have a 48 V, 20 Ah battery. Can somebody tell me if I can add the second battery to the bike.

I really can't understand that how the difference in Ah will affect my eBike?
Please tell me if I can use it.

Comment: Larger Ah will give you more run-time, as long as the new battery can discharge at the same rate (or more) than your old battery, you should be fine.

Comment: Ah is a measurement of battery capacity.  The thing to look for is if the new battery can supply the current required by your bike.  This is measured in A (Amps).  You should really check this, but my best guess is that it is okay.  The 20Ah battery will just last longer.

Comment: That the charger will take longer to give a full charge is obvious, but if the charger is safety smart, and thinks it's still a 13Ah battery, it may quit before full charge because 'the battery is taking too long to charge, something's wrong, safety shutdown'.

Answer (score 2):

The analogy is: Can I drink water from a large bottle or a small bottle?

The answer is: The large bottle contains more water so it will last longer than a smaller bottle.